# How to check the nested event is trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In this example , I would like to trigger swiperight function first , and check whether the book is "pressed" . How to turn the bind "pressed" into a conditional statement? thank you.

```
    $(document).swiperight(function(){
      $("#book").bind("pressed", function(event) {   //  Change this statement to   if ($("#book") is "pressed"){..}
           console.log("pressed");
      });
});
```

Comment: What is #book? And is `pressed` also a property or whatever?

Comment: book is an div , pressed is a event of #book

Comment: An event of `book`? Are you trying to check if there is a function bound to that event already?

Comment: Ok, but is issued depending on some conditions take a look at what are those and use them.

Comment: So when pressed occurs, in that event track the state. What's the problem?

Comment: can i change it to a if else statement?

Comment: *** because I would like to use the case where the #book is not "pressed"

Comment: Which is the behaviour of the "pressed" event? If it's like a 'click' the answer of @Yury Tarabanko seems the one to go. If it's not like a 'click', more details are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#book").click(function(event) { 
    var $this = $(this);
    //emulate toggle button
    $this.data("pressed", $this.data("pressed") ? '' : 1);     
});

$(document).swiperight(function(){
   if(!$("#book").data("pressed")) { //If not pressed
      //your code goes here
   }
});
```

Comment: I was writing the same thing (not on 'click', but on 'pressed', pretending 'pressed' is a custom event). Anyway I suppose it will also need a control to track when '#book' is 'unpressed'.

Comment: I am not the one downvote . Yes @Polmonite get the idea.  I would like to do when the something only when the book is unpressed

Comment: I've added ToggleButton like behaviour. If book is clicked it is marked as pressed, if it is clicked again it is unmarked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).swiperight(function(){
      if($("#book").attr("pressed") === "true") {
          $("#book").bind("pressed", function(event) {
              $(this).attr("pressed", "true");
              console.log("pressed");
          });
      }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no native "pressed" event so I guess it's a custom event you trigger yourself, using `$("#book").trigger("pressed")`. If this is the case, before triggering the event add a flag:

```
$("#book").data("pressed", "true")
$("#book").trigger("pressed")
```

Then whenever you want to check:

```
if ($("#book").data("pressed") === "true") {
    //already pressed...
}
```